# External Video Hosting - will it eat my bandwidth?

Tags: video

I hav asked this question before, on serverfault, but have been unable to get a clear answer or spammy ones.

A client runs a website with limited bandwidth per month (10gb) but wants his users to be able to download hq videos.

Now if he would rent hosting space on amazon, for example, the downloads would still go through his website right? So would this then still eat his bandwidth then, or not?

It there a way to circumvent this? How do you do this, if you have limited bandwidth?

If you are kind enough to answer, please don't spam me with what is good and not good hosting, I already know.

Answer (score 6):

If the video file is hosted elsewhere then it won't eat their bandwidth since it is coming from a completely different server assuming you are not reading the file through a server side script of your own first but directly linking to the hosted file itself. If they have bandwidth issues this is exactly how they should solve it (or find a new host with a better bandwidth offering.

Comment: The *user* always uses the bandwith.  Sometimes users don't get this... it's bizarre.  Like, streaming video doesn't "count"... people amaze me :)

Comment: Yea, bandwidth is still consumed on page load, but the actual video wouldn't consume any of the actual server's bandwidth. Great example is YouTube and embedding videos.